# Как при создании поста, добавлять данные в другие таблиц?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Как сделать так чтобы при создании поста, я мог заполнять данными другие таблицы?
То есть сейчас есть сама БД в которой имеются таблицы (posts, stores, offers, author).
Создал контроллер

**PostController**

```php
function store(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'name'=>'required',
        ]);

        $posts = Posts::query()->create([
            'name' => $request->get('name'),
            'description' => $request->get('description'),
        ]);
        $posts->getStoreForPost()->create([
            'url' => $request->get('url'),
            'link_book' => $request->get('link_book'),
            'price_book' => $request->get('price_book'),
        ]);

        return redirect()->route('posts.index');
    }
```

При создании пишет ошибку, поле не может быть пустым в таблице stores.
Как я понял, я не указал ему что при создании он должен брать данные поста(чтобы указать поле post_id в таблице).
Вот модель по которой работает взаимосвязь

**PostModel**

```php
public function getStoreForPost()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Store::class);
    }
```

Вот сама форма добавления поста

**views.posts.create**

```html
<form method="post" action="{{ route('posts.store') }}">
    @csrf
    <div align="center">
        <div style="padding-bottom: 25px;">
            <label for="name">Название</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
        </div>
        <div style="padding-bottom: 25px;">
            <label for="description">Описание</label>
            <input type="text" name="description" id="description">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="stores" align="center" style="padding-bottom: 10px;">
        <button class="store_add" type="button">Добавить поле</button>
        <div>
            <label for="getStoreForPost">магазин</label>
                <input type="text" id="url" name="url[]">
                <input type="text" id="link_book" name="link_book[]">
                <input type="text" id="price_book" name="price_book[]">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div align="center">
    <button type="submit">добавить пост</button>
    </div>
</form>
@endsection

@push('script')
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(".store_add").on('click',function(){
            $(".stores").append(
              `<div>
                 <label for="getStoreForPost">магазин</label>
                   <input type="text" id="url" name="url[]">
                   <input type="text" id="link_book" name="link_book[]">
                   <input type="text" id="price_book" name="price_book[]">
              </div>`
            );
        });
        
    });
@endpush
```

Answer (score 0):

Ну если прям совсем просто, то создаёш сначала пост, а потом в стор создаёш мультиинсёртом записи с post_id, где post_id - это id новосозданого поста - это как вручную, работать будет.

```
$brand = Brand::find(1);
$product = new Product();
$product->name = 'iPhone X';
$product->slug = 'iphone-x';
$product->price = '899.99';
$product->qty = 10;
$product->description = 'Some description';
// Сохраняем связанную модель
$brand->products()->save($product)
```

это если посложнее, оставлю ссылку - почитай:
https://laravel.demiart.ru/one-to-many-relationship/

Я не заметил где у тебя в другой связаной модели прописана связь, должна быть еще что такое

`return $this->belongsTo(Brand::class);`

А ошибка есть, потому что у тебя в базе скорее всего прописано, что поле post_id не может быть null, и ты просто не сказал ему какой id туда записывать. Надо как то так:[image: инсёрт масива]

Comment: `public function post() {return $this->belongsTo(Post::class);}` данная функция у меня имеется, я при помощи её вывожу данные которые только что заполнил в базе данных в ручную. Но я так и не понял даже после прочтения данного кода предоставленного вами, как добавлять данные в другие таблицы.

Comment: попробуй добавить в масив post_id, и записать в это поле id нового поста, созданого до этого, можеш еще один запрос добавить, хоть там и есть функция, по которой можна обратиться к посту, на моей картинке это показано, тоесть получится как-то так:

``````$posts->getStoreForPost()->create([
            'post_id' => $posts->id
            'url' => $request->get('url'),
            'link_book' => $request->get('link_book'),
            'price_book' => $request->get('price_book'),
        ]);``````